# how to pass ffmpeg output to other sub-class in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, ffmpeg

i want to pass the thumbnail generated by ffmpeg to save_FTPUpload where the save_FTPUpload function is to upload the image file to ftp server. how can i do that?
here is my example code for thumbnail generation using ffmpeg and "fileupload" function for uploading files to ftp server:

```
public partial class testtttt : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        generateThumbnail();
        string fi_attachment = @"C:\2.jpg";//source image file
        save_FTPUpload(fi_attachment);
    }

    private void generateThumbnail()
    {
        string thumbpath, thumbname, videofile;

        videofile = "http://www.xxxx.com/video.Avi";
        thumbpath = @"C:\";
        thumbname = thumbpath + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(videofile) + ".jpg";

        string thumbargs = "-i \"" + videofile + "\" -vframes 1 -s 60*30 -ss 00:00:00 -f image2 \"" + thumbname + "\"";

        Process process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe");
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = thumbargs;

        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        try
        {
            process.Start();
            string output2 = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            string output3 = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            if (process != null)
            {
                process.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.lblMessage.Text = "Thumbnail created successfuly";//ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }

    public bool save_FTPUpload(string fi_attachment)
    {
        bool fileSaved = false;
        //string fi_attachment = @"C:\1.jpg";
        string filename = "3.jpg";//image name to be saved in ftp
        string ftp_user = "*****"; //username
        string ftp_pass = "*****"; //password
        string ftpURI = "ftp://www.xxxx.com/thumb/"; //ftp path where the image will be saved

        while (!fileSaved)
        {
            string file_ftpURI = string.Format("{0}/{1}", ftpURI, filename);
            FtpWebRequest file_exist_request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(file_ftpURI);
            file_exist_request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftp_user, ftp_pass);
            file_exist_request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
            try
            {
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)file_exist_request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                if (response.StatusCode ==
                    FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable)
                {
                    FtpWebRequest upload_request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(file_ftpURI);
                    upload_request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftp_user, ftp_pass);

                    upload_request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                    upload_request.UsePassive = true;
                    upload_request.UseBinary = true;
                    upload_request.KeepAlive = false;

                    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(fi_attachment))
                    using (Stream upload_request_stream = upload_request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        fs.CopyTo(upload_request_stream);
                    }
                    FtpWebResponse upload_response = (FtpWebResponse)upload_request.GetResponse();

                    fileSaved = true;
                    this.Label1.Text = "Upload Successful";
                }
            }
        }
        return fileSaved;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You determine the output filename that ffmpeg will use, so why not use that?

The file name that is used can also appear in the standard output, but again you already know it because you chose it yourself.

So if generateThumbnail would return thumbname you could pass that to FTPUpload.

Comment: sorry for the noob question but how can i pass thumbname to FTPUpload?

Comment: One solution would be to change `private void GenerateThumbnail()` into `private string GenerateThumbnail()`. Then put `return thumbpath;` at the end of the function. Use `string fi_attachment = GenerateThumbnail();` to generate the thumbnail.

Comment: thanks for your guidance. I tested what u recommend and it work great. ffmpeg can generate the image file and save it in folder and then FTPUpload will upload the file to FTP server. But how if i want to pass the value(image file) directly from ffmpeg to FTPUpload without ffmpeg save it first?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can do that unless ffmpeg can give you a filestream or something similar.